How to pass data from middleware to API route using NextJS 14
I can't find any solution using nextjs14, all example from internet seems outdated. I am trying to use header but I am getting null.
// middleware.ts
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
  const headersList = headers();
  const authorization = headersList.get("authorization");

  if (!authorization) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "No Creds" });
  }
  const [, token] = authorization.split(" ");
  try {
    const payload: JWTPayload = await verify(token, supabaseJwtSecret);


    const headers = new Headers(req.headers);
    headers.set("userId", "XXXXXX12345679");
    return NextResponse.next();

 // other code

}

I expect to get the userId to my api route
// route.ts
export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const supabase = createRouteHandlerClient({ cookies: () => cookieStore });

  const headersList = headers();
  const userId= headersList.get("userId");
  console.log(userId);
// result should have userId

}


middleware.js: You should convert data with JSON.stringify()


const headers = new Headers(req.headers);
headers.set('userId', JSON.stringify(body));
return NextResponse.next({ headers: headers });



API Route:


export async function GET(req) {
    try {
        const body = await req.headers.get('userId');
        console.log(body);

        return NextResponse.json({ message: `User return success` }, { status: 200 });

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return NextResponse.json({ message: error.message }, { status: 500 });
    }
};



